# Deploying multiple applications on tomcat when startup of one depends on the other

Tags: tomcat

I was asked this question in an interview. There are two applications, application A and application B. Application B depends on Application A, So allow the deployment of application B only when A has already been deployed and started. Can someone please help me on how to configure it in tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

In application A , implement a simple HTTP API which can be as simple as just return 200 status. In application B , implement logic that will call this API during it starts up (e.g. by using `ServletContextListener`) . If it receives 200 status code , it means application A is already deployed and started. Otherwise , application A has some problems or even does not start yet , hence stop starting application B.

It sounds like a general system design question and I am not aware there are any tomcat specific features the can help in implementing such things.